# Capture system.out.println output in Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I have a Java project deployed on Tomcat 9. This project uses java.util.logging. Logger for logging. We receive our output in the /var/log/tomcat directory in catalina.log (actually it ends up being catalina.[date].log, for example today's file is called catalina.2021-11-11.log).

A third-party payment processing API we use is failing. The developer of that API told me how to enable his API to output logging messages, which he says are going to System.out.println. However, I cannot find any of these messages. They don't appear in my catalina log file, or any other file in my logs directory.

I don't completely trust this developer and I'm not sure his code is really doing what he says, but assuming it is, should I be able to see the output in catalina.log? Is there some configuration change I can make to ensure that I see it?

Comment: The distrust is called closed source!

Comment: stdout is handled by whatever starts up tomcat - systemd typically on a current Linux host. If that's the case you see the entries using journalctl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging System.out.println to log file for single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564602/logging-system-out-println-to-log-file-for-single-application)